# Transform multi-line log to JSON using Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I need to create a scala based transformation to process log files (sample below) to a json based format.

The data between "START" and "END" is always key/value based and there are finite (~30) possible keys - all are optional.

```
START
FirstName=John
LastName=Parker
City=Sydney
State=NSW
Country=Australia
END
START
FirstName=John
City=Melbourne
Country=Australia
END
START
FirstName=Peter
LastName=Parker
Country=France
END
```

The output (or transformed) format should look like:

```
[
  {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "LastName": "Parker",
    "City": "Sydney",
    "State": "NSW",
    "Country": "Australia"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "John",
    "City": "Melbourne",
    "Country": "Australia"
  },
  {
    "FirstName": "Peter",
    "LastName": "Parker",
    "Country": "France"
  }
]
```

I am new to scala/spark. However, so far I've been able to put up some logic as below

```
  var logBlockMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]()
  var full_json_list = new java.util.ArrayList[String]()
  val parsedRDD = dataRDD
    .foreach{
      case "START"=>
        //Initialize data collection
        logBlockMap.clear()
      case "END" =>
        //Add the map data
        val json_string  = mapper.writeValueAsString(logBlockMap)
        full_json_list.add(json_string)
      case line =>
        val newline = line.split("=")
        logBlockMap.put(newline(0), newline(1))
    }
```

However, I quickly run into problems when processing a large file as the full_json_list grows bigger and things fall apart quickly.

What would be an ideal spark way to solve this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by "fall apart"? Like do you run out of RAM?

Comment: Since I'm storing the results of processing in this variable "full_json_list", I believe I'm not leveraging the power of spark. When the results are collected, the variable "full_json_list" has GB worth of data in memory before it's written to the file